# How to actually search for a song in a mediastore cursor using a string

Tags: android

I have set up the cursor but I am still struggling with actually searching it. How do I search for the track name? How do I get its ID so I can pass it to mediaplayer? I have tried different things but didn't succeed.

Basically, I want to know how to search the mediastore for a certain string (string songToPlay in this case), get the results, get the ID of the best match and pass it to my mediaplayer service to play it in the background. The only thing I am asking you is how to get the ID though.

This is the code I am using:

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] songToPlay = value.split("play song");
    String[] searchWords = songToPlay[1].split(" ");
                String [] keywords = null;
                StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
                where.append(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " != ''");
    String selection = where.toString();
                    String[] projection = {
                            BaseColumns._ID,   
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, 
                            MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                            MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
                    };
for (int i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
                        keywords[i] = '%' + MediaStore.Audio.keyFor(searchWords[i]) + '%';
                    }

                Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, keywords, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);              
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do{
                        test.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
```

I'm very confused and most of this code is from the internet. I have been trying to do this for 2 days now, that's why I'm asking here. I've done hours of trying by myself.

edit: Current code. How am I supposed to find the location - music ID or whatever I need to play that song from the cursor?

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            String songToPlay = value.replaceAll("play song", "").trim();
            int music_column_index;
            String[] projection = {
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,   
                    MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE
            };


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor cursor = this.managedQuery(uri, 
                    null, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?", 
                    new String[]{songToPlay}, 
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will search the `MediaStore` for all songs with title equal to the value of your `songToPlay` string.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    null, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?", 
    new String[]{songToPlay}, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

You can then of course query the cursor to get the ID (and any other column) of any results.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
    long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));
    // Whatever else you need
}
```

However this will require an exact match, you may like to use the `LIKE` operator for a more fuzzy match.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking for too much but I'm really stuck. I really still have no idea about DB queries. How am I supposed to get the file location or music ID from the cursor after declaring the cursor? I am almost depressed - I can't make progress with this for over 2 days now. I have put my current code in the original post.

Comment: Hi Ken, this is a very useful answer, thanks for posting it. I would just like to know if you could elaborate on the LIKE operator? I have got this code to work but as you stated, it requires the exact song name, how can I make it so that when I am searching, it will populate songs that contain characters I am searching for? thank you very much.

Comment: I have also created another question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31843094/querying-mediastore-as-you-search-via-an-edittext