# Querying MediaStore as you search via an EditText

Tags: android, mediastore

I am trying to figure out how I can query the MediaStore for specific characters as I search via my EditText.

My current solution for searching the MediaStore [came from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17965275/2657363)

And as Ken states, you have to input the name of the song exactly for anything to come up.

I would like to know how to make it so that when I gradually input a song name, it finds the songs that have the same characters in the name that I am entering into my EditText.

Here's my code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
null, 
MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?", 
new String[]{songToPlay}, 
MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=?",
new String[]{songToPlay},
```

with

```
MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " LIKE ?",
new String[]{"%" + songToPlay + "%"},
```